# Actualizar los índices de un objetos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, javascript-objeto

Tengo estos dos arrays de objetos como datos de entrada:

```
let relations = [
  {
    "header": "NOMBRE", 
    "property": "NAME"
  },
  {
    "header": "CORREO",
    "property": "EMAIL"
  },
  {
    "header": "TAMAÑO",
    "property": "SIZE"
  }
];

let dataInput = [
    { 'NOMBRE': 'Jairo Sosa', 'CORREO': 'jairo@gtg.cl', 'TAMAÑO': '15' },
  { 'NOMBRE': 'Luis Torres', 'CORREO': 'luis@gtg.cl', 'TAMAÑO': '20' }
]
```

Lo que intento hacer es reemplazar todos los indices de dataInput por su **property** de la variable relations y obtener como resultado algo asi:

```
let data_result = [
    { 'NAME': 'Jairo Sosa', 'EMAIL': 'jairo@gtg.cl', 'SIZE': '15' },
    { 'NAME': 'Luis Torres', 'EMAIL': 'luis@gtg.cl', 'SIZE': '20' }
]
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La lógica detrás de la solución es la siguiente:

1. Iterar por cada objeto dentro tu array principal.
2. Obtener todos los atributos de cada objeto.
3. Transformar esos atributos a su "traducción", buscandolo en el array de `relations`.
4. Finalmente, sólo debes crear un nuevo objeto con los nuevos atributos y los valores del objeto original.

Paso a paso:

1. Iterar por cada objeto dentro tu array principal: Puedes utilizar `map()`

   ```
   const results = dataInput.map(item => {
      ...
   })
   ```
2. Obtener todos los atributos de cada objeto en cada iteración:

   ```
   let attributes = Object.keys(item);
   ```
3. Transformar esos atributos a su "traducción", buscandolo en el array de `relations`: Aquí puedes utilizar `find()`.

   ```
   let newAttributes = attributes.map(element => {
      const newName = relations.find(e => e.header === element);
      return newName ? newName.property : element;
   });
   ```

   Dado que los atributos que encontraste en el paso anterior es un array que contendrá:

   ```
   ["NOMBRE", "CORREO", "TAMAÑO"]
   ```

   Debes recorrerlos con un `map()` y obtener el nuevo valor de cada ítem.

   ```
   const newName = relations.find(e => e.header === element);
   ```

   Con el método `find()` simplemente comparas si el header es igual a alguno de los elementos en tu array de atributos, entonces lo encontraste.

   ```
   return newName ? newName.property : element;
   ```

   Aquí, si lo encontraste satisfactoriamente, retornas el property, si no simplemente retornas el mismo valor.
4. Finalmente, sólo debes crear un nuevo objeto con los nuevos atributos y los valores del objeto original.

   ```
    let newObject = {};
    let index = 0;

   for(let attr in item) {
       newObject[newAttributes[index]] = item[attr];
       index++;
   }

   return newObject;
   ```

Aquí adjunto el código completo:

```js
let relations = [
  {
    "header": "NOMBRE", 
    "property": "NAME"
  },
  {
    "header": "CORREO",
    "property": "EMAIL"
  },
  {
    "header": "TAMAÑO",
    "property": "SIZE"
  }
];

let dataInput = [
    { 'NOMBRE': 'Jairo Sosa', 'CORREO': 'jairo@gtg.cl', 'TAMAÑO': '15' },
  { 'NOMBRE': 'Luis Torres', 'CORREO': 'luis@gtg.cl', 'TAMAÑO': '20' }
];
  

const mapped = dataInput.map(item => {
   let attributes = Object.keys(item);
   let newAttributes = attributes.map(element => {
      const newName = relations.find(e => e.header === element);
      return newName ? newName.property : element;
   });
   
   let newObject = {};
   let index = 0;
   
   for(let attr in item) {
       newObject[newAttributes[index]] = item[attr];
       index++;
   }
   return newObject;
});

console.log(mapped);
```